# Object reference not set to an instance of an object with listview databound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list view that loads with the page, but i want to hide a button with a condition.

I get this error message 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Even thought the commandName has a value.The code is under the listview databound.

This my code:

```
protected void PostListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item == null)
            return;

        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("deleteButton");

        if (currentUserId.ToString() == btn1.CommandName.ToString())
        {
            Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("deleteButton");
            btn1.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        {
            Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("deleteButton");
            btn1.Visible = false;
        }
    }



<asp:ListView ID="PostListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="POSTDataSource2" OnItemDataBound="PostListView_ItemDataBound" OnLoad="PostListView_Load">
                                <AlternatingItemTemplate>

                                    <p class="text-muted">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-right" Width="50px" CommandName='<%# Eval("UserId") %>'  />
                                    </p>
                                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Comment: On what line do you get the exception?

Comment: `e.Item == null` is redundant, it is never null.

Comment: @mason if (currentUserId.ToString() == btn1.CommandName.ToString())

Comment: @Musa Probably `btn1` is null, it can't be found. Post your markup for the ListView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @mason Thanks i have posted it

Comment: Your markup has `</li>`, `</ul>`, and `</div>` tags without matching start tags. Your button has an extra closing tag.

Comment: @mason its just a snippet of the code

Comment: @Musa That's probably part of the problem. In order to locate the incorrect part, you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the [`ItemType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.itemtype(v=vs.110).aspx) in `ItemDataBound`:

```
protected void PostListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("deleteButton");

        if (currentUserId.ToString() == btn1.CommandName.ToString())
        {
            Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("deleteButton");
            btn1.Visible = false;
        }

        else
        {
            Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("deleteButton");
            btn1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```